# Need to replace UIWebView UITextField keyboard

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiwebview, uitextfield

I'm using `UIWebView` to display formatted content. However, I need to replace the default keyboard for `UITextViews/UITextFields` with our own.

I can use grotesque methods to hide the default keyboard when it appears, but I can't find the text field to direct input to. `UITextFieldTextDidBeginEditingNotification` or `UITextViewTextDidBeginEditingNotification` is never fired off. I do see `UIKeyboardWillShowNotification` etc properly emitted.

It is important that the final result be App Store approved.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:

When the keyboard notification comes, note which HTML element is focused. Then make your view controller first responder.

```
[self becomeFirstResponder];
```

Your view controller should become first responder and return your custom input view.

```
- (BOOL)canBecomeFirstResponder {
    return YES;
}

- (UIView*)inputView {
    return _customInputView;
}
```

When your custom input view gets input, you can pass it to the HTML element.

```
NSString* script = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"element.value += '%@';", input];
[_webView stringByEvaluatingJavascriptFromString:script];
```

Comment: Sadly, I can't find any UITextField objects to modify. I use inputView for our own objects, but UIWebView doesn't seem to actually create them. I've done a dump and I don't see one at least.

Comment: I've edited my answer to suggest a way to implement your requirement.